# Open a tab in browser from a Chrome App

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app

Since the permission `"tabs"` and `chrome.tabs` API are not available in Chrome Apps, how can I open a tab in the browser with specified URL?

Comment: window.open should still work the way it always does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try dynamically creating a link and call its `click` method.

```
function openTab(url) { 
    var a = document.createElement('a'); 
    a.href = url; 
    a.target='_blank'; 
    a.click(); 
}
```

You could then call that function like this:

```
openTab('http://google.com');
```

**Update**

The previous example opens the link in the default browser (which could be something other than Chrome)

If you want to force the link to open in chrome, use `window.open`

```
window.open('http://google.com');
```

Comment: What if my default browser is not Chrome?

Comment: @SamikSaha in that case you could use `window.open` .. eg.  `window.open('http://google.com')` , that should always open Chrome when called from within a Chrome App (answer updated)

Comment: Unfortunately `window.open` also opens the link in default browser

Answer (score 3):

In your manifest file, add `"browser"` to your permissions:

```
"permissions": ["browser", ...],
```

Then in your js file, call function `chrome.browser.openTab` to open your link on Chrome.

```
 chrome.browser.openTab({
   url: "your_url"
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is now [chrome.browser.openTab](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/browser#method-openTab) which should do what you want